# Sqlite NullPointerException on either first or last row

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, cursor

I've searched high and low through null pointer and query posts, but still can't resolve this. I am inflating a ListView with a custom adapter, then registering it with an ItemLongClickListener which raises a context menu. The context menu is populated with data retrieved from the database that inflated the ListView...same number of rows, obviously...but when I query the first item (position '0' passed in for the int id), I get an exception. But if I increment it by one after it's passed in, I get the same exception on the last row instead. All the other rows show the queried data just fine. I can include more complete code, but I think I'm missing something more fundamental here...any ideas? Thanks in advance, my first question--please let me know, too, if my posting needs to be done differently!

```
listview.setAdapter(new MyCustomAdapter(text, image));
listview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View strings,
                int position, long id) {
            // showToastMessage("" + position);
            showDialogOnLongClick(position);
            return true;
        }
});
```

The dialog builder, which makes a call to a database function:

```
private void showDialogOnLongClick(int position) {
    Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    // AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    ArrayList mSelectedItems = new ArrayList();

    ArrayList<String> listInfo = getListInfo(position);

   ...

}
```

And, the actual query of the database:

```
    // Getting single list item data
public ArrayList<String> getListInfo(int id) {
    DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    database = helper.getReadableDatabase();
    //to increment, or not to increment?
    id++;
    // Cursor cursor =
    // database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM list_data WHERE _id ='"+ id +"'",
    // null);
    Cursor cursor = database.query("list_data", new String[] { "listTitle",
            "listContent", "dateCreated", "dateModified" }, "_id = " +     id
            + "", null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null && (cursor.getCount() > 0))
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("listTitle")));
    result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("listContent")));
    result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dateCreated")));
    result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("dateModified")));

    return result;
}
```

The logCat:

```
03-25 15:13:20.113: E/AndroidRuntime(12639): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 15:13:20.113: E/AndroidRuntime(12639): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-25 15:13:20.113: E/AndroidRuntime(12639):    at com.baked.listanywhere.ActivityMain.showDialogOnLongClick(ActivityMain.java:310)
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: if ``cursor`` returns 0 columns you never call ``moveToFirst`` thus the cursor will be in an ``IllegalState``. Secondly, you do not close the cursor, I'd recommend ``try{ //blablalbla}finally{cursor.close()}``. Lastly, what guarantee do you have that the ids exist in the db?

Comment: As I said, the rows were generated from the table data; if I have, say, 3 rows, positions 0, 1, and 2, I would want to query 1, 2, and 3 id's...I'm still failing to see why querying 3 throws an exception. Closing the cursor (a good recommendation) didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but when I query the first item (position '0' passed in for the int id), I get an exception.

Attempting to find a row with an id of 0 will most likely return an empty Cursor, a SQLite `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` should always be greater than zero.  Rather than pass `position` try passing `id`, if your custom Adapter is a CursorAdapter then the `id` parameter in `onItemClick` is the current row's id.

---

This code will throw an exception when the Cursor is empty, because you cannot read data from a non-existent row:

```
if (cursor != null && (cursor.getCount() > 0))
    cursor.moveToFirst();

...
result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("listTitle"))); // Exception!
```

A better approach is to check the result from `moveToFirst()`:

```
if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    ...
    result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("listTitle")));
}
```

---

As for:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.baked.listanywhere.ActivityMain.showDialogOnLongClick(ActivityMain.java:310)
```

What is line 310 in MainActivity?

Comment: Rearranging the moveToFirst as suggested didn't change the exception on the last row...line 310, strangely enough, is in the custom adapter, which isn't being called on the context menu...I'm still stuck, sorry :( (I can add the adapter code if I could figure out how to do that...) Is it necessary to use a cursor in Android?

Comment: Thanks, Sam...it turns out the query was fine and returns my values, I was performing an illegal operation on one of the (empty) returned values. Your comment about line 310 made me look further into that, so I'll give you the answer vote.